# Overlapping of pop-up:

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have given a link to the first pop-up which in turn will open another pop-up.The problem is that the 2nd pop-up is opening behind the 1st pop-up.Is it  possible to open the 2nd pop up ahead of the 1st pop up using z-index or by using overflow:hidden ? OR instead of that I can simply close the first popup using window.close();  and then give href to a new pop-up,but I think this method can be used only for windows not for popups.Is possible to do it for pop-ups?
After clicking on login my first pop-up will be displayed and inside that pop-up after clicking on the register it will open 2nd pop-up behind 1st pop-up.
My code:

```
<li><a href="#<?php //echo base_url  ?>index.php?r=user/login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" data-nav-section="testimonials" onclick="enable_all()"><span>Log In</span></a></li>
<div class="col-md-12 paddingTop2" > Already registered ? &nbsp;
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Register</a>
```

Please tell me if you need data-target

Comment: Why are you asking us if it's possible? It's your job to test these methods before coming here.

Comment: I have many options but don't know which one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Used z-index that has more than of the amount of the first pop-up.

For example:

> Pop-Up 1 has z-index: 1;

then for Pop-Up 2, make it z-index: 2;

NOTE: Don't forget to add a CSS Position for it. Otherwise, it will not work even if you increase the value of z-index.